# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Bluetooth and Uart (Rx/Tx)

Tags: android, android-things

People, I am trying to use Bluetooth to read some data and read/write from a Rx/Tx serial too (Gpio 16 and 15 respectively) using *Android Things dev preview 3*, but seems that it not work.

Looking at https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html, *Configuring the UART mode* section, it seems like I have to choose between Bluetooth and Uart (Rx/Tx). (Please correct me if I am wrong)

There is some way to read/write on Uart and read/write from Bluetooth together ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Raspberry Pi has a single full-speed UART (UART0) that is multiplexed between various board functions. You may need to modify the boot configuration of the system to enable the functions you need for your application. The following modes are supported:
>
> Bluetooth Mode: Bluetooth functions are enabled. Pins BCM14 and BCM15 expose the serial debug console.
>   Note: Bluetooth mode is enabled on the board by default.
>
> Application Mode: Bluetooth functions are disabled. Pins BCM14 and BCM15 expose UART0 via Peripheral I/O.

Correct.

UART0 is the interface and you can only use it for Bluetooth or another UART function one at a time.

https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html

AndroidThings does also expose UART over the USB controller, so technically you could use another UART device this way with something like this...

[image]

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=usb+to+uart

Comment: well yeah, it only has so many pins, but I looked at the other AndroidThings boards (the pinout diagrams) and they all only seem to have one set of pins for UART